# Алгоритм TwoFish

Tags: c#, криптография, алгоритм

Приветствую всех!
Интересует алгоритм twofish реализованный на C#. В интернете ничего внятного не нашел к сожалению. Может у кого-то есть или ссылка например :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Можно взять готовую реализацию на С/C++ собрать ее и подключить к проекту на C# через Pinvoke. Эталонные исходники здесь: [Twofish Source Code](http://www.schneier.com/twofish-download.html)
2. Можно взять готовый код из существующего проекта, например, [C# implementation of the Twofish cipher](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2593/A-C-implementation-of-the-Twofish-cipher).

Или создать свой собственный на основе [SymmetricAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.aspx) из System.Security.Cryptography.

```
public sealed class Twofish: SymmetricAlgorithm {
    public Twofish() {
        this.LegalKeySizesValue = new KeySizes[] {
            new KeySizes(128, 256, 64)
        };
        this.LegalBlockSizesValue = new KeySizes[] {
            new KeySizes(128, 128, 0)
        };
        this.BlockSize = 128;
        this.KeySize = 128;
        this.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        this.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

    }

    public override ICryptoTransform CreateEncryptor(byte[] key, byte[] iv) {
        Key = key;

        if (Mode == CipherMode.CBC) IV = iv;

        return new TwofishEncryption(KeySize, ref KeyValue, ref IVValue, ModeValue, TwofishBase.EncryptionDirection.Encrypting);
    }

    public override ICryptoTransform CreateDecryptor(byte[] key, byte[] iv) {
        Key = key;

        if (Mode == CipherMode.CBC) IV = iv;

        return new TwofishEncryption(KeySize, ref KeyValue, ref IVValue, ModeValue, TwofishBase.EncryptionDirection.Decrypting);
    }

    public override void GenerateIV() {
        IV = new byte[16] {
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        };
    }

    public override void GenerateKey() {
        Key = new byte[KeySize / 8];

        for (int i = Key.GetLowerBound(0); i < Key.GetUpperBound(0); i++) {
            Key[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    public override CipherMode Mode {
        set {
            switch (value) {
            case CipherMode.CBC:
                break;
            case CipherMode.ECB:
                break;
            default:
                throw (new CryptographicException("Not supported."));
            }
            this.ModeValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! 
Про сорсы я знаю, но принципиально не хочу использовать Pinvoke.

Answer (score 3):

Возьмите [BouncyCastle под C#](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) и не мучайтесь - он реализует TwoFish.